# How to add response headers in apache camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

Here I am getting the request from client and just redirecting the request and sends the response to client. I want to add headers to response. Could you please guide me, how to add headers to response for below mentioned code.

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<camel:route trace="true" id="ProxyRepo2">
    <camel:from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8299/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true" />
        <camel:to uri="http://localhost:8081/overdraft/getCostmerDetailsAsJSONData/?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
</camel:route>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `setHeader` at the end of the route to set the response headers you want. When Camel reached the end of the route it uses the current message as-is as the response.

`<camel:route trace="true" id="ProxyRepo2">
    <camel:from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8299/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true" />
    <camel:to uri="http://localhost:8081/overdraft/getCostmerDetailsAsJSONData/?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
    <camel:setHeader headerName="foo">
        <camel:constant>Hello I was here</camel:constant>
    </setHeader>
</camel:route>`